# Responsive navigation has scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been messing with a bootstrap theme for Wordpress and when I shrink down the navigation it turns into a scroll bar. This is odd because it should be overlaying.

The website is: http://sendtohim3dprinting.co.uk/

and this is how it looks:
[image]

I can't quite figure it out.

These are the CSS changes I made:

```
.navbar {
    height: 110px;
    background: #2476bf;
}
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    max-width: 850px;
    height: 110px ;
}
.menu-item a {
    height: 110px;
    width: 200px;
}
li.menu-item.menu-item-object-page a, .menu-item-type-custom, .menu-item-type-custom.menu-item-object-custom.menu-item-2413 a {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive ;
    font-size: 1.5em;

}
.collapse.navbar-collapse {
    float: right;
}
```

And the original CSS for the nav bar is extremely long but can be found [here](http://sendtohim3dprinting.co.uk/wp-content/themes/bootstrap-canvas-wp/css/bootstrap.css?ver=4.2.4)

I've not encountered this kind of issue before in regards to the scroll bar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `height: 110px` to `height: auto` or remove it.

Comment: Changed it to auto, but now when I press the nav it pushes the page down and doesn't sit ontop

Answer (score 0):

Just add `overflow: hidden` to your `.nav > li` class. Like this one:

```
nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to hide the horizontal scroll bar as in the image above, you can try:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>
```